# Python (pandas): How to read data by chunks in a long file where chunks are separated by a header and are not equal in length?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data in a single txt file:

```
00001+++00001   000031         12.8600    -1    7     BEAR

     1990052418  276.00  18.80     0.00  12.86

     1990052500  276.00  19.70     0.00  12.86

00002+++00002   000047         30.8700   995   22     LION

     1990072206  318.10   8.80  1010.00  12.86

     1990072212  316.80   8.90  1010.00  12.86

     1990072218  315.40   9.30  1010.00  12.86

     1990072300  313.60   9.30  1010.00  12.86

00003+++00003   000050         36.0100   973   37      BIRD

     1990072412  285.00  34.00  1012.00  10.29

     1990072418  286.20  33.60  1013.00  10.29

     1990072500  287.30  33.00  1013.00  10.29
```

How can I read each (unequal) chunk under each header separately in Python (Pandas)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution which parses each block (without reading in the entire file):

```
def read_fwfs(text_file):
    res = {}
    with open(text_file) as f:
        header = f.readline()
        block = []
        for line in f:
            if "+++" in line:
                #  End of block, so save it to dict as DataFrame.
                #  Note: this next line could be pulled out as a function.
                res[header.split("+++")[0]] = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("".join(block)), header=None)
                #  Reset variables.
                header = line
                block = []
            #  Ignore blank lines.
            elif line != "\n":
                block.append(line)
        #  Save the last block.
        #  Note: See what I mean about being a function? Here it is again:
        res[header.split("+++")[0]] = pd.read_fwf(StringIO("".join(block)), header=None)
        return res

In [11]: d = read_fwfs("my_text_file.txt")
         d
Out[11]:
{'00001':             0    1     2  3      4
          0  1990052418  276  18.8  0  12.86
          1  1990052500  276  19.7  0  12.86,
 '00002':             0      1    2     3      4
          0  1990072206  318.1  8.8  1010  12.86
          1  1990072212  316.8  8.9  1010  12.86
          2  1990072218  315.4  9.3  1010  12.86
          3  1990072300  313.6  9.3  1010  12.86,
 '00003':             0      1     2     3      4
          0  1990072412  285.0  34.0  1012  10.29
          1  1990072418  286.2  33.6  1013  10.29
          2  1990072500  287.3  33.0  1013  10.29}

In [12]: d["00003"]
Out[12]:
            0      1     2     3      4
0  1990072412  285.0  34.0  1012  10.29
1  1990072418  286.2  33.6  1013  10.29
2  1990072500  287.3  33.0  1013  10.29
```

*If you want to do something more with the splitting line, e.g. use it as a header, you could add that into the read_fwf part e.g. by adding the second half of the split header to the joined block. As I mention inline, it's probably a good idea to pull that part out as a function anyway.*

Comment: @Storm which pandas version are you using?

Comment: I got the following error:
Error at line 8 above (res[heade.split("+++")] =...)
ValueError: must specify only one of "withds" and "colspecs"

Comment: @Storm which version of pandas are you using? This works for 0.17.1.

Comment: Ok, I tried it in pandas 0.17.1 but now I get a long error message pointing at line 8 above ( res[header.split("+++")[0]]=.....) then pointing at line 19 in read_fwf, then pointing at......, until: 

  File "/Users/uma2103/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2395, in detect_colspecs
    max_len = max(map(len, rows))

ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @Storm weird, can you paste a gist of the entire stack trace https://gist.github.com/ ? Are there some empty blocks (no non-empty lines between +++ lines)? cos that might do this.

Comment: Sure, please see here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/df20c0a404076e7556d5

and the txt file here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f08b45d343b66c2846ed

Comment: @Storm well. that file and the function above works for me in pandas 0.17.1. Strange! I recommend putting some print statements in the code, or better exploring with %debug. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Like I say, that error happens when `blocks==[]` which it never is in the text file your provide. You could use an if-block to protect against that case (i.e. read the fwf only `if blocks:`).

Comment: It actually worked! Turns out the txt file was not formatted correctly.
Thank you so much. I truly appreciate your help!

Comment: Fantastic! Please can "accept" this answer so as to mark it as working :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/184179

Comment: Hello Andy... How can I message you if I have a similar question?

Comment: @Storm Please post it as another question on StackOverflow like this one, that way it'll get more eyes than just mine, but feel free to add the link here when you do.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034577/python-pandas-how-to-read-grouped-data-separated-by-headres
Excuse me being a bit sloppy as I'm new to stackoverflow, but appreciate all the help I'm getting.