# Python Pandas: How to read grouped data separated by headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the date in text file:

```
AL012015,               Kevin,     20,
20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , ZZ, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
AL022015,               Mike,     20,
20151108, 1800,  , XX, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , YY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
```

I would like to read each chunk under AL012015, as follows:

```
d['01']:
20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , ZZ, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
d['02']:
20151108, 1800,  , XX, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
20151108, 1800,  , YY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
```

note that 01 and 02 are the two digits after AL

Comment: Thank you MaxU for editing my question. I am new to Stackoverflow and not quite sure how to post questions the way you edited mine.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You might want to read something like this: https://python4astronomers.github.io/files/asciifiles.html

Comment: Hi @Storm. Do you need a solution exclusively base on `pandas`?

Comment: Hi @ej_f. Not necessarily. Any solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can apply a preprocessing. Using `awk` to obtain a new file with the digits in a additional column as follow:

```
$ awk -F, '/^AL/ {AL=substr($1,3,2);next}{print AL","$0}' file.txt
01,20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
01,20151108, 1800,  , XY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
01,20151108, 1800,  , ZZ, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
02,20151108, 1800,  , XX, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
02,20151108, 1800,  , YY, 22.2A,  71.5B,  30, 10,
```

Then, you can use `pandas` more comfortable with a `groupby` operation. Let's suppose that the previous output is on `file2.txt`, you can do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file2.txt",sep=",",header=None)
for gr,data in df.groupby(0):print(gr,"\n",data)
1 
   0         1     2   3    4       5        6   7   8   9
0  1  20151108  1800       XY   22.2A    71.5B  30  10 NaN
1  1  20151108  1800       XY   22.2A    71.5B  30  10 NaN
2  1  20151108  1800       ZZ   22.2A    71.5B  30  10 NaN
2 
   0         1     2   3    4       5        6   7   8   9
3  2  20151108  1800       XX   22.2A    71.5B  30  10 NaN
4  2  20151108  1800       YY   22.2A    71.5B  30  10 NaN
```

I hope this can help you.

Regards.

Comment: nice and fast solution !

Comment: Fantastic solution! Many thanks!
Would you please provide a simple explanation of the awk command above?

Comment: Sure. If the line starts with AL (/^AL/) store the substring in the AL variable and move to the next line (AL=substr ($1,3,2);next) else print the previous variable beside the line (print AL","$0 )